# How to habilitate the leaflet map draw for all browsers in a PWA app?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, progressive-web-apps, react-leaflet

We are developing an application for farmers and part of the process is done using the leaflet map component to draw the plots location.

Our application is a PWA and runs perfectly in firefox, the draw component works well.

However the draw map component in the google chrome, brave, opera doesn't work.

If you want to try look at [App mobile](http://dapp.agryo.com) , install using the google chrome or others than Firefox.

Any tips our suggestion of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We find the problem. 
It was about the draw mode in "continuous" and no in "step-by-step".